# parse pdf from url on java. can i use jsoup?

Tags: java, pdf, jsoup, pdf-parsing

i have the url : http://pasca.undiksha.ac.id/e-journal/index.php/jurnal_bahasa/article/view/500 (it's not directly access pdf, but directed to pdf file. I want parse this pdf file and get pdf text. i try using jsoup : `

```
String url = "http://pasca.undiksha.ac.id/e-journal/index.php/jurnal_ep/article/download/380/172";
File in = new File(url);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());`
```

the output is :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\pasca.undiksha.ac.id\e-journal\index.php\jurnal_ep\article\download\380\172 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:36)
        at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:103)
```

Any have idea?thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use URLConnection to connect the pdf
read content using :

```
URL url = 
new URL( "http://pasca.undiksha.ac.id/e-journal/index.php/jurnal_bahasa/article/view/500" );

URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

input = connection.getInputStream();

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

Comment: Jsoup.parse for inputStream type, it needs three parameters. 
    parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri)

Comment: JSOUP can be used for this purpose....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708911/download-a-large-pdf-with-jsoup

Comment: what is this parameter in => Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");
I feel "in" should be "input" which come from => input = connection.getInputStream();

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `File` with URL other than `file://`, of course it would be an error.
use [commons-http-client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to access your file on the web.