# Download a large pdf with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I would like to download a large pdf file with jsoup. I have try to change timeout and maxBodySize but the largest file I could download was about 11MB. I think if there is any way to do something like buffering. Below is my code.

```
public class Download extends Activity {

static public String nextPage;
static public Response file;
static public Connection.Response res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    nextPage = b.getString("key");
    new Login().execute();
    finish();
}

private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.eclass.teikal.gr/eclass2/")
                    .ignoreContentType(true).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .execute();

            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(
                    MainActivity.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            String username1 = pref.getString(MainActivity.PREF_USERNAME,
                    null);
            String password1 = pref.getString(MainActivity.PREF_PASSWORD,
                    null);
            file = (Response) Jsoup
                    .connect("http://www.eclass.teikal.gr/eclass2/")
                    .ignoreContentType(true).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .maxBodySize(1024*1024*10*2)
                    .timeout(70000*10)
                    .cookies(res.cookies()).data("uname", username1)
                    .data("pass", password1).data("next", nextPage)
                    .data("submit", "").method(Method.POST).execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/download/";
        String name = "eclassTest.pdf";
        FileOutputStream out;
        try {

            int len = file.bodyAsBytes().length;
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH + name));
            out.write(file.bodyAsBytes(),0,len);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I hope somebody could help me!

Comment: did you try to set ```.maxBodySize(0)``` and ```.timeout(0)``` in order to set no limits on these parameters?

Comment: @luksch thank you for your reply, I have tried this but the largest file I could download was 11-12 MB.

Comment: You are running this as an Android activity right? Are you sure that this is an issue with jsoup and not just the activity being killed when the OS tries to free up memory?

Comment: @asp Yes, I run it as Android activity but I'm not sure what is the problem. I send you the LogCat to help you more.
http://prntscr.com/35gdr8
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 4):

I think, it's better to download any binary file via HTTPConnection:

```
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/file.pdf");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
        }

        // this will be useful to display download percentage
        // might be -1: server did not report the length
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Jsoup is for parsing and loading HTML pages, not binary files.

Comment: I have no problem to use HTTPConnection but I don't know how to login (with cookies) and you don't write. If you know how to do this, write and I'll try it.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: Consider searching for how to use cookies with HttpURLConnection, rather than passively waiting for an answerer to provide more help.  If you can't find the answer yourself, ask another question!  This time, I've searched for you, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153) may help.